# sudo as www-data file permissions

Tags: linux, apache, bash, permissions

I have a problem with calling a bash script using apache webserver as www-data.

I get an IO error when I call it from the server and it doesn't give me the whole output of the program, but only '] No such file or directory' of a file that I create in the script about halfway through the script.

So I wanted to see further details, and I figured this would be a way to run the program in the exact same way, but just through terminal so I could see more of the output:

`sudo -u www-data ./bashscript`

However, upon doing this, I didn't get any error and my bash script fully completed.

So what is the difference between doing a sudo call as www-data, and calling a script versus actually calling the script as www-data through the web-server? 
and more importantly, I can get the actual server call to get the same output as the sudo call?

I'm using python cgi for my webpages right now so I just use subprocess to make system calls, here is my code, although I don't think that's the problem:

```
w = subprocess.Popen("./nameofscript",  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
for line in w.stdout.readlines():
    print line
kill = w.wait()
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure apache has access to folder with this script.

Try to use full path to the script.

If you use python script please be sure the script is executable and it has #! "shebang" at first line.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Q1:

> what is the difference between doing a sudo call as www-data, and
>   calling a script versus actually calling the script as www-data
>   through the web-server?

I would say, running as `sudo` from you OS prompt, you are able to receive more information when a failure or missuse happends, while sometime running from a browser or from a program langage shell call, you may just not receive any feedback even when the command never ran.

And Q2:

> I can get the actual server call to get the same output as the sudo
>   call?

Not sure how do it in python, but in php you have this two instructions: [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php) and [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php), using the second one, you may get an output as a returnung value.